# Overriding Protocol default implementation in test target

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have a protocol in my main target:

```swift
protocol Animatable: UIView {
    static var shouldAnimate: Bool { get } 
}
```

and default implementation in my main target:

```swift
extension Animatable {
    static var shouldAnimate: Bool { return true } 
}
```

and object that conform to this protocol that **do not** have implementation of `.shouldAnimate`:

```swift
class MyView: Animatable { }
```

in my **test target** I would like to override default implementation so I wrote:

```swift
extension MyView {
    static var shouldAnimate: Bool { return false } 
}
```

Somewhere else in a code of my main target I wrote `print(MyView.shouldAnimate)` end I expected to see output:

1. If I run only main target `true`
2. If I run my tests `false`

But when In both cases I see `true` and default implementation is always firing from this protocol? Why? Shouldn't this be overriden with class implementation when running test target?

Comment: Are you trying to mock the static method?

Comment: Not mock - from my understanding I should be able to override my method - so sth more like dependency injection kind. I'm using default protocol implementation in my target, but want to override this when I'm firing a test target

Comment: Since the `doSth` call is written in the main target, it doesn't know or care about what's in the test target. So really, you need a way to check whether tests are running.